# How to automatically convert Excel 95 file to Excel 2003

Tags: excel, vbscript, automation

I have much many Excel 95 Files and I require them in a newer format (say Excel 2003 format).

is there a way to do so in Java?

is there any way to automate this?

thanks,

Yoni

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to do it *with Excel.* I don't know why you would want to bring Java into it. Orders of magnitude more complicated.

Comment: I presume it's related to the number of excel files involved.

Comment: @Nick of course it is, but Excel is scriptable for tasks like that.

Comment: can you please add a script how to do so?

Comment: @Yoni: I suggest you retag your question from Java to VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

[jExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)